# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager giving Request failed error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]; //not working with or without this.

NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"id", @"id", @"pwd", @"pwd", @"func", @"func", nil];

[manager POST:@"http://someurl.com/abc/func.php" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

why I am getting

> Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed:
>   unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0x1f89e740
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://someurl.com/abc/func.php,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable
>   content-type: text/html}

Comment: What are you trying to post?...

Comment: @ACommonMan nsstring based ID and Password, which is defined in parameters dictionary.

Comment: What does your server respond with and what format (content type) is the data?

Comment: @DavidCaunt after adding manager.requestSerializer and manager.responseSerializer i a getting (null) from server, but if i directly access from browser i am getting correct data.

Comment: AFNetworking 2 requires a response serializer that can process your response. So if your response is JSON, you need to provide an [AFJSONResponseSerializer](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.2/Classes/AFJSONResponseSerializer.html), for example

Comment: @DavidCaunt i am not using json, i am simply calling a php function and expecting plain text.

Comment: Then you'll need to post the actual URL you are using or I don't think anyone can help

Comment: @DavidCaunt i am currently testing on local url, cant share that :-(